# (HTML Scraping) XPath of a column changes based on color

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to parse through all of the values in the column of [this website (with different stock tickers)](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=acco&ty=c&ta=1&p=d). I am working in Python and am using XPath to scrape HTML data.

Lets say I want to extract the value of the "Change" which is currently 0.62% (and green).  I would first get the tree to the website and then say.

```
stockInfo_1 = tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[12]/b/span/text()')
```

I would then get an array of values and last element happens to be change value.

However, I noticed that if a value in this column has a color, it is in the `/b/SPAN`, while if it does not have a color, there is no span and its just in the `/b`.

So to explain:

```
stockInfo_1 = tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[12]/b/span/text()')
```

^this array would have every value in this column that is Colored

```
while stockInfo_1 = tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[12]/b/text()')
```

^would have every value in the column that does not have a color.

The colors are not consistent for each stock. Some stocks have random values that have colors and some do not.  So that messes up the `/b/span` and `/b` array consistency.

How can I get an array of variables of ALL of the values (in order) in each column regardless of if they are in a span or not?  I do not care about the colors, i just care about the values.

I can explain more if needed.  Thanks!!

Comment: What are you using to scrape the data? bs4? scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly skip intermediate tags in xpath and get all the values in a list by using `//` inbetween.

So the snippet should be

```
tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[12]/b//text()')
```

This skips all the intermediate tags between  and text.

I've tried using lxml. Here is the code

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url="https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=acco&ty=c&ta=1&p=d"
resp=requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.content)
values = tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[12]/b//text()')
print values
```

Which gives output as follows

```
['0.00%', '-2.43%', '-8.71%', '-8.71%', '7.59%', '-1.23%', '1.21', '0.30', '2.34% 2.38%', '12.05', '12.18', '1.04%']
```

> ***Note:*** If you don't want to hardcode 12 in the above Xpath you can aslo use `last()` as `tree.xpath('//*[@class="table-dark-row"]/td[last()]/b//text()')`

[Xpath cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14) for your kind reference.

[Using "//" And ".//" Expressions In XPath XML Search Directives In ColdFusion](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2142-using-and-expressions-in-xpath-xml-search-directives-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: I will test it out later although I like where you are going.  Thank you!

Comment: Worked.  Thank you so much!